# does anybody have a simple pprof use on a go-executable?

Tags: go

I have looked at the article about [profiling go programs](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs), and I simple do not understand it. Do someone have a simple code example were the performance of code snippet is logged in text file by a profile-"object"?

Comment: What sort of profiling information are you looking for? The pprof tool in golang can provide quite a lot of different information. A useful one I've found is the listing functionality which just outputs source code with the number of samples taken on each line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the commands I use for a simple CPU and memory profiling to get you started.

Let's say you made a benchmark function like this :

File something_test.go :

```
func BenchmarkProfileMe(b *testing.B) {
 // execute the significant portion of the code you want to profile b.N times
}
```

In a shell script:

```
# -test XXX is a trick so you don't trigger other tests by asking a non existent specific test called literally XXX
# you can adapt the benchtime depending on the type of code you want to profile.

go test -v -bench ProfileMe -test.run XXX -cpuprofile cpu.pprof -memprofile mem.pprof -benchtime 10s

go tool pprof --text ./something.test cpu.pprof           ## To get a CPU profile per function

go tool pprof --text ./something.test cpu.pprof --lines   ## To get a CPU profile per line

go tool pprof --text ./something.test mem.pprof           ## To get the memory profile
```

It will present you the hottests spots in each cases on the console.